# How to put log in box in a website to ensure one user can vote once only?

Tags: facebook, voting, voting-system

I have a school project to do which requires us to develop an online voting website. how do i ensure one user has voted once only?

the website is supposed to be in booths in public places which means i cannot use ip addresses or cookies. i was planning to use fb login id or maybe some other email id but i cannot find relevant codes/links. i just want people to go through the procedure of entering the log in id but not go to fb directly.

my website cannot be published online.

could you please suggest how i can achieve this? it is a bit urgent, thank you!

Comment: generate some tokens. Give those tokens out. Once they have been "used" to vote, invalidate them so they cannot be used again. You won't be able to use FB for this without the website being "online" so FB can see it.